# WinEdt cannot locate the specified .tex and .bib files

Tags: macros, miktex

My laptop OS crushed and I did a fresh re-installation. I have installed WinEdit 8.1, 64-bit, and MiKTeX 2.9, 64-bit. However, I am trying to compile a TeX file but it returns the following error:

> system cannot find the specified file

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Did you install MikTeX or WinEdt first? I think you should check the WinEdt configuration and verify the paths to the compiler (pdflatex I think) and to bibtex. I have not a windows machine near right now for explain you better. But perhaps there is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No need of re-installing anything. Go to `Options` → `Execution Modes`. In the window that opens correct the paths in `TeX System`, `Ghostscript` (if you want), and `PATH` tabs.

[image]

Finally you may check your system using `Diagnosis` tab in the same window.